# Arrays become undefined after I console.log them

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to create a series of arrays which have 10 values in them that I can use for calculations.

My code is like such (js):

```
 $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'page.php',
    success: function(data){
        // declare all arrays holding valuable statistics
        var csArray = [];
        var assistArray = [];
        var killArray = [];
        var gameTimeArray = [];
        var championArray = [];
        var deathArray = [];
        var jungleCSArray = [];
        var counterJungleCSArray = [];
        var roleArray = [];
        var laneArray = [];
        var crowdControlArray = [];


        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.minionsKilled;
            csArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.assists;
            assistArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.kills;
            killArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].matchDuration;
            gameTimeArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].championId;
            championArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.deaths;
            deathArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle;
            jungleCSArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle;
            counterJungleCSArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.role;
            roleArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].timeline.lane;
            laneArray[i] = value;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            var value = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats.totalTimeCrowdControlDealt;
            crowdControlArray[i] = value;
        }
        console.log(csArray);
        console.log(assistArray);
        console.log(killArray);
        console.log(gameTimeArray);
        console.log(championArray);
        console.log(deathArray);
        console.log(jungleCSArray);
        console.log(counterJungleCSArray);
        console.log(roleArray);
        console.log(laneArray);
        console.log(crowdControlArray);
```

When I go to my browser, it console.logs properly:

[image]

But when I try to type something like:

```
console.log(killArray[1]);
```

I get the following message:

```
ReferenceError: killArray is not defined.
```

Ultimately I'm trying to use these numbers in calculations downstream and I'm getting "NaN" returns. After troubleshooting and figured out that my arrays seem to cease to exist, I figured its probably trying to add null values to other null values and returning NaN's.

My calculations are as follows:

```
            //ALGORITHM START
        for (i=0, i<10; i++;){
            switch(roleArray[i]) {
                case "DUO":
                    //assumes top lane duo
                    var role = "L";
                    console.log(role);
                    break;
                case "DUO_CARRY":
                    //assumes bot lane adc
                    var role = "A";
                    console.log(role);
                    break;
                case "DUO_SUPPORT":
                    //assumes bot lane support
                    var role = "S";
                    console.log(role);
                    break;
                case "SOLO":
                    //assumes mid or top solo
                    var role = "L";
                    console.log(role);
                    break;
                case "NONE":
                    //assumes jungle, check lane
                    var role = "J";
                    console.log(role);
                    break;
            }
        }

         switch(role){
             case "L":
                 var aFactor = 1.00; //kills
                 var bFactor = 0.66; //assists
                 var cFactor = 0.75; //deaths
                 var dFactor = 0.80; //cs
                 var eFactor = 0.20; //jungle cs
                 var fFactor = 0.55; //counter jungle cs
                 var gFactor = 0.50; //cc time
                 break;
             case "A":
                 var aFactor = 1.00;
                 var bFactor = 0.10;
                 var cFactor = 1.00;
                 var dFactor = 1.00;
                 var eFactor = 0.20;
                 var fFactor = 0.30;
                 var gFactor = 0.33;
                 break;
             case "S":
                 var aFactor = 0.20;
                 var bFactor = 2.00;
                 var cFactor = 0.33;
                 var dFactor = 0.10;
                 var eFactor = 0.33;
                 var fFactor = 0.55;
                 var gFactor = 2.00;
                 break;
             case "J":
                 var aFactor = 1.00;
                 var bFactor = 1.50;
                 var cFactor = 0.75;
                 var dFactor = 0.33;
                 var eFactor = 1.20;
                 var fFactor = 1.60;
                 var gFactor = 1.00;
                 break;
            }

            //FORMULA
            for (i=0; i>10; i++){
            var pvpFactor = ((aFactor * killArray[i]) + (bFactor * assistArray[i])) / (cFactor * deathArray[i]);
            var pveFactor = ((dFactor * csArray[i]) + (eFactor * jungleCSArray[i]) + (fFactor * counterJungleCSArray[i])) / (gameTimeArray[i]);
            var auxFactor = (gFactor * crowdControlArray[i]);

            var rawHMC = (0.8 * pvpFactor) + (0.4 * pveFactor) + (2.5 * auxFactor)

            var HMCarray = [];

                console.log (rawHMC);
                HMCarray[i] = rawHMC;

            }


        }

    });
```

});

`The console.log (rawHMC);` returns a NaN value.

Basically my question is: Why can't I console.log my arrays, and why am I getting a NaN return? Is it something with my array loops or my switch statements?

Thanks!

Comment: create a fiddle for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arrays are ONLY known inside the success handler. You need to move them outside that scope to see them outside that scope.
If you AFTER the success try to console.log the vars, they are gone.

Here is how to have one var hold all arrays and have one loop update them all.

```
// declare all arrays holding valuable statistics
var statsArr = {
  csArray      :[],
  assistArray  :[],
  killArray    :[]
}; // no comma on the last
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'page.php',
  success: function(data){

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
      var stats = data.matches[i].participants[0].stats;
      statsArr.csArray.push(stats.minionsKilled);
      statsArr.assistArray.push(stats.assists);
    }
```

The arrays are now in global scope held in the statsArr object.

To use later:

```
var pvpFactor = ((aFactor * statsArr.killArray[i])
```

Comment: the arrays are still inside the success handler, are they not?

Comment: i guess you can't see the whole code cause i split it into two parts, but my program shows that the braces corresponding to teh success codeblock are inclusive to essentially all of my code

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this out but I have a feeling it will work. Been a while since I programmed so a couple concepts have left my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand two things: variable scope, and asynchronous callbacks. You can probably find lots online about these, so I'll just give brief definitions:

- variable scope is *where* a variable is visible; to make programs easier to follow, languages allow you to keep parts isolated from one another, and in JS, every variable is only visible inside the function where you write `var`, plus functions defined inside that block
- asynchronous callbacks change *when* a variable is defined; you don't know how long the AJAX request will take, so you let JS run other code while it's waiting, and when it gets a response, your `success` callback fires.

So the first thing you need to do is define variables in a scope where all your code can see them, by placing your `var` statements correctly. Then, you need to make sure the code that reads from them doesn't run before the code that writes to them, by thinking about when callbacks will run.